# Display only the .TS file that is playing in FFPLAY

Tags: ffmpeg

I am using ffplay to play my m3u8 streams.

My question is there a way to make ffplay less verbose and only show me TS chunk file that it is playing.

When it plays it displays a large amount of verbose meta-data.

**For Example:**

```
 Duration: N/A, start: 23565.722678, bitrate: N/A
  Program 0 
    Metadata:
      variant_bitrate : 0
    Stream #0:0: Video: hevc (Main) ([36][0][0][0] / 0x0024), yuv420p(tv), 2400x2720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 15:17], 60 fps, 60 tbr, 90k tbn, 60 tbc
    Metadata:
      variant_bitrate : 0
    Stream #0:1: Audio: aac (LC) ([15][0][0][0] / 0x000F), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp
    Metadata:
      variant_bitrate : 0
    Stream #0:2: Data: timed_id3 (ID3  / 0x20334449)
    Metadata:
```

**[https @ 0x7f4d98009700] Opening 'https://MyTSChunk.ts**

I have tried the various loglevel commands (e.g. silent, panic etc) but haven't found the combination to give me the following:

## Example of what I am looking to achieve:

*#Input to Terminal*

ffplay http://www.myMpegStream.m3u8

*#OUTPUT to Terminal*

mychunk1.ts
mychunk2.ts

Answer (score 0):

There is no option in ffplay to do that. You can pipe stderr to a tool like sed or awk and parse the output however.